# How did sailors navigate before the Mercator projection (1536)?

Tags: navigation, history, mercator

The Mercator projection (1536) must be great for nautical navigation. It allows one to find a bearing and keeping this constant one should reach the target (if not in the shortest line). But how did people navigate before this? As an example Magellan circumnavigated the globe ca. 1520.

Comment: People navigated using the stars

Comment: I wish I would give more +1 to @Maksim

Comment: navigation by stars only works without cloud cover the Vikings navigated with their senses... http://sciencenordic.com/how-vikings-navigated-world

Comment: You would be interested in reading The Age of Reconnaissance by J. Parry he writes a good summary on nautical navigation https://books.google.co.uk/books/about/The_Age_of_Reconnaissance.html?id=6l5rXRkpkFgC&hl=en

Comment: Did Magellan really *circumvent* (avoid) the globe? Wiki says he *circumnavigated* the globe https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ferdinand_Magellan, damn spell checker! good question though. A quite a lot of the early sailors either stayed on well known paths (trade routes) or hoped they hit land before they ran out of supplies (and teeth - Scurvy). One theory is that pre-history discoveries come from fishermen blown by storms and finding land, not navigating at all but just surviving, but that's just speculation.

Comment: @MichaelMiles-Stimson that's just so funny, made me laugh out load!

Comment: Interestingly Magellan never actually circumnavigated the globe as he died in the Philippines whilst fighting the Lapu-Lapu tribe. Only two of the three ships made it back because of the resulting lack of people after the conflicts in the Philippines. The key person, in authority, who made it back was Juan Elcano master of the Victoria.

The whole story can be read here: http://www.amazon.co.uk/Over-Edge-World-Laurence-Bergreen-ebook/dp/B0018ND8B6/ref=sr_1_1?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1435650089&sr=1-1&keywords=over+the+edge+of+the+world this is entertaining read!

Comment: Also for anyone really interested in the voyages of Magellan the translated story written by Antonio Pigafetta (he traveled on the voyage) can be bought here: http://www.amazon.co.uk/Magellan-Francis-Guillemard/dp/1906421005/ref=sr_1_5?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1435650134&sr=1-5&keywords=magellan A bit heavy to read but, as the primary source for the voyage story very interested anyway :-)

Comment: @MichaelMiles-Stimson: ;-). I learn something new every day.

Comment: I will add that the compass has been known since early Egyptian times (a piece of Magnetite on a reed in a bowl of water) so keeping a bearing wasn't so difficult - knowing what bearing to take is another story. Have a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thor_Heyerdahl about the Ra II expedition taking a papyrus boat from Egypt to South America to prove the Incas were descendants of Egyptians.

Comment: the Q is off-topic, as there's no tie in to GIS, ...but darn interesting! My tangential contribution in [chat], ...[here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/22682789#22682789)

Comment: Very carefully!......I'll show myself out.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about the history of navigation, and not about using GIS.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There are a variety of ways to navigate across oceans without the aid of maps and in particular the Mercator Projection. It is worth noting that before the invention of the chronometer (calculation of longitude) in 1764 there wasn't a reliable way of measuring longitude when out-of-sight of land.

Most of the history I have read includes the Mediterranean Sea where navigation would, in ancient times, either take place **along coastal routes** or through **celestial navigation** (following stars) to navigate across open ocean. One of these longer routes is the famous voyage of Nearcho from India to Susa after Alexander's campaigns into India. It is worth noting that there is eveidence of charting and the intriguing [Antikythera mechanism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antikythera_mechanism) that will have aided ancient Greek peoples in the Mediterranean Sea.

In Northern Europe Viking tribes used **stones** (Iceland Spar) to locate the sun in the sky when it was obstructed from view (very helpful in Northern Europe) to aid with following the sun across open water.

Some early navigational tools include:

1. **Mariner's Compass**
2. [**Portolan Chart's**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portolan_chart) that include only a compass rose to indicate
   bearing
3. [**Astrolabe**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Astrolabe)
4. [**Jacob's Staff**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacob%27s_staff)
5. [**Sextant**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sextant)

One of the keystone methods is **dead-reckoning**. This is where the navigator finds their position by measuring course and direction. You start from a known location and using a compass measure bearing and taking into account speed, through measuring [knots](http://engineering.mit.edu/ask/why-speed-sea-measured-knots) on a rope, pin where you are most likely to be (two men would work with one running and counting the number of knots that pass whilst another turns a sand-timer, thus calculating how far you have travelling in a set amount of time). Of course this is easily erroneous, but it's the best you can do until the chronometer and GPS came about :-).

The above tools would have been available to sailors during the 15th-16th Century (upto 1536) and mainly helped in accessing your latitude (i.e. the angle of [Polaris](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pole_star)).

Before the publication Christopher Columbus (1492) "discovered" America, Vasco da Gama voyaged round Africa to India (1498), and Ferdinand Magellan's voyage (1522) circumnavigated the Earth, navigation was primitive but functional, although I believe through a bit of luck a lot was accomplished.

Navigation would have been through a combination of the tools above and due to **other environmental variables** such as using known prevailing wind directions and signs of land.

Have a look at the [The Age of Reconnaissance](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=6l5rXRkpkFgC&pg=PA83&source=gbs_toc_r&cad=3#v=onepage&q&f=false) he does a thorough examination of Navigation.

Answer (score 6):

Simple answer?  They didn't really.

Their routes are mostly coast-hopping.  When they left the known coasts (i.e. crossing non-contiguous continents), they really hadn't a clue where they were.  Latitude was OK with a star chart, but longitude was impossible until the chronometer was invented.  Dead reckoning runs out of accuracy pretty quickly, and fails completely in bad weather.

Remember that Columbus thought he'd hit India (hence "West Indies" and "native American Indians"), which gives you some idea of the state of navigation at the time.  Magellan followed Da Gama's route across the Atlantic, but Da Gama hadn't a clue where he was either.  Magellan coast-hopped round South America until he reached about the same latitude as he started (which is something he *could* tell from stars), at which point he just went due east and hoped he ran into land before he ran out of food and water.

Comment: Thank you Graham! Just having looked at some images of old maps I understand what you mean by coasthopping; the geography of Africa is very well understood since it can be explored from the coast whereas the geography of south and north america is almost unexplored and not understood.

Comment: NO. Columbus didn't thought he arrived in India because of bad navigation, but because he calculated the size of the planet wrong. This is why his contemporaries didn't believe he could reach India: they knew the size of the Earth and knew nobody could make a journey that long given the ships of the era. Columbus thought he arrived in India because he hit land at the approximate location (based on the time he traveled) he thought India should be.

Comment: IIRC In addition to the error in the size of the planet, also at the time no-one was quite sure how large Eurasia was. Combined, these place Asia much closer to the west of Europe, across a single ocean, than it is in relaity. See e.g. the Toscanelli map (there's an image floating around of that map's data reprojected onto the Mercator projection) or the Erdapfel.

Answer (score 5):

Polynesian navigation

The Polynesians observed and learned a star catalog of declination and right ascension--This allowed them to ( a ) identify and name a navigation course, ( b ) transmit it orally to another navigator, ( c ) follow such a course.

My understanding is that they learned "chains"--a chain is a sequence of stars that rise at approximately the same angle away from the observed celestial pole (either North or South) The chain is characterized by ( i ) angular deviation from the pole, and ( ii ) phase correspondence to day of the year and time of night.

Island locations in the ocean can be discovered because it reflects ocean swells in rings concentric with the island. A navigator familiar with the major swells can follow a (reflected) cross-swell directly towards such an island.

This wikipedia article mentions these, and gives a much fuller description.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynesian_navigation